# Why mpifort wrapper is not found after installing mpich and openmpi?

Tags: fortran, mpi, gfortran

I need to compile a program that uses mpifort wrapper to create some executables files for multiporcessor usage. (OPENTELEMAC)

I have tried to install mpich and OpenMPI to get this wrapper but it doesn't seem to work. I am using gfotran to perfom this operations.

Could somebody explain to me how do I get this installed?

I am using Ubuntu 14.0 LTS.

Comment: Why do you need mpifort? Why can't you just use mpif90?

Comment: The truth is I am not confident yet in this area, so I managed to compile Telemac properly  in my laptop using mpifort. I read up on the topic and its appears that is prefereble to use mpifort over 90 and 77. I had problems before for using structures that were diffrent ( f90, f95, f77) . But i have no reasons not to use it, just I do not know if it will work. Thanks for replying.

Comment: There is no difference between these, really. I have no idea what you might have read.

Comment: Current OpenMPI uses mpifort, while mpich probably sticks with mpif90 for the same purpose.  You must take care to install so that you can bring just one of these on to PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH, which may mean removing versions which come with Ubuntu and following the instructions posted for the MPI implementations.

Comment: If you don't like to set configuration variables, you can use alias to make mpif90 appear as mpifort.  That may not paper over any problems if your app works only with openmpi but you want it to work with mpich.

Comment: Hi  it is solved. I change my  path to mpif90 and it compile just fine. I removed the one that was already installed in Ubuntu and just put the one I wanted. Thanks.  Chelo.